# Issue Converting varchar to nvarchar mysql

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this is an easy question, I am coming to MySQL from SQL Server.

When I execute my create statement it contains nvarchar but commits to the database as varchar. Even in my alter statement afterwards the column does not change at all. Does the collation or DB engine make a difference?

During execution I am not encountering any issues in results, other than the fact the column changes datatype. I attached a screencast of my activity http://screencast.com/t/wc94oei2

I have not been able to find anyone with similar issues through my Google searches

Comment: You should show some of your code, queries and/or table schema. That would help us understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: I've just created table like you and it's described as varchar, but when I start alter table with 'nvarchar' I get message that nothing has changed and then when I 'describe' table it's still varchar. On the other hand, when I created varhar column and then run the same alter table, I got a message that something has been change but after 'describe' it's all the time 'varchar'. So I think it's call simply varchar regardless of wheter it's varchar or nvarchar.

Comment: @guillaume I do in the screencast, but I could do something like CREATE TABLE test ( test nvarchar(50) ).  But I think I know the issue, you have the option to do nvarchar, but mysql saves it as varchar like varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8. Since we use nvarchar for utf-8. But when you look on workbench you only see it saved as varchar. Kind of confusing

Comment: Paste the code in the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean, this..

CREATE TABLE `stars` (
  `idstars` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` nvarchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idstars`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Name_UNIQUE` (`Name`)
)
----turns to---
CREATE TABLE `stars` (
  `idstars` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idstars`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Name_UNIQUE` (`Name`)
)