# Column declared as NVARCHAR gets created as VARCHAR in MySQL. Both VARCHAR AND NVARCHAR declaration can store non latin characters

Tags: mysql, varchar, sqldatatypes, nvarchar

I am unable to create `NVARCHAR` data type in MySQL.

I have the following query -

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( column1 NVARCHAR(10) );
```

This is supposed to create `column1` that stores data type `NVARCHAR(10)`. But the query -

```
DESCRIBE table1;
```

gives me the output -

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| column1 | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Thus instead of column1 that can store `NVARCHAR(10)` data type, column1 that can store  `VARCHAR(10)` data type gets created.

Now only `NVARCHAR` data type is supposed to store non Latin characters.

But the query -

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ("भारत");
```

Runs successfully without any error. Here "भारत" is a Hindi word in Devanagari script which in English sounds "Bharat" and translates to "India".

The query -

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

gives display as expected -

```
+--------------+
| column1      |
+--------------+
| भारत         |
+--------------+
```

I guess may be MySQL treats `VARCHAR` internally as `NVARCHAR`. But I can't find any documentation stating so.

The following is a link from MySQL developers website -

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-national.html

Here it says that `NVARCHAR` is fully supported.

To find out if non Latin characters can be stored in a column defined as `VARCHAR` I ran the following queries -

```
CREATE TABLE table2 ( column2 VARCHAR(10) );
DESCRIBE table2;
```

This gives me the output -

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| column2 | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here column2 that can store `VARCHAR(10)` data type gets created as expected.

Running the query -

```
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ("भारत");
```

runs without any error.

and the query -

```
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

gives expected output -

```
+--------------+
| column2      |
+--------------+
| भारत         |
+--------------+
```

Thus even if I declare column2 as `VARCHAR(10)` I can successfully store non Latin characters (here Devanagari characters of Hindi language).

The most logical conclusion is that regardless of declaring a column as `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` MySQL always internally stores it as `NVARCHAR`. But I can't find any documentation regarding the same.

The following stackoverflow question gets closest to my question -

[Issue Converting varchar to nvarchar mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234492/issue-converting-varchar-to-nvarchar-mysql)

But there is no answer provided to the question.

I am using operating system Ubuntu 20.04 and MySQL version - 8.0.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which information you can save is stored in character set and collation.

so as the default is utf8, bith can save hindi or chines or kisuali in their 4 byites

but

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( column1 NVARCHAR(10),column2 VARCHAR(10) );
```

Actually is treated slightly different

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `column1` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

in the sample database the Default is

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

But the national varchar is like the standard defines

```
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

For your hindi word  "भारत" it makes no differenz, but for some charachters there can be "problems"

Comment: No offense, but I am a SQL newbie and it is difficult to understand your answer.  For example - "`SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`",  "`ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`", "`DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`", "`CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`" - I can't understand anything of it

Comment: a database has a defualt character set and collation in my case `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`but when you define a nvarchar you see in the example it uses `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`so it is a differnet collation. If your database has a different default collation the `SHoW CREATE TABLE table1` could show you a different output  for the databse defualt but it would should always `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`for nvarchar

Comment: What is collation?

Comment: a set of rules see https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation/ that explains it quite nicely and you find there more topic to explore

Comment: Chinese has some characters that need utf8mb4, hence cannot be stored with utf8.

Comment: "Character set" is how to _encode_ characters in byte(s).  "Collation" is how to _sort_ characters.

Comment: What is "kisuali"?

Comment: A language in africa

Answer (score 1):

Get in the habit of using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead of `DESCRIBE`.  It would have answered your question.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE nv ( column1 NVARCHAR(10) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 3720 | NATIONAL/NCHAR/NVARCHAR implies the character set UTF8MB3, which will be replaced by UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using CHAR(x) CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous. |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE nv\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: nv
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `nv` (
  `column1` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The Warning gives you a hint of an important problem, should you ever try to store Chinese or Emoji in the column.  `utf8mb4` is needed.

So, you should say

```
CREATE TABLE nv ( column1 VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 );
```

That is, don't use NVARCHAR, use VARCHAR and specify the appropriate character set.

utf8 happens to be OK for DEVANAGARI, as in your example.

Comment: Why have you appended `\G` to `nv` in the line - `mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE nv\G`? What does `\G` does? For me `SHOW CREATE TABLE nv` shows your output without needing `\G`. Appending `\G` as in `SHOW CREATE TABLE nv\G` shows me the same output as well but in this case after the output I get an error message - `ERROR: No query specified`. Why is it so? What query MySQL is asking me to specify? Thank you.

Comment: `\G` is handy in the "mysql" commandline tool.  (Note that it _replaces_ the `;`.)

Comment: What is difference between using `\G` and `;`

Comment: Also how to insert non-English integer numbers and perform integer calculations on those non-English numbers? Thank you.

Comment: @PayelSenapati - Most languages, including MySQL's flavor of SQL, work only with Arabic numerals.  If, by "non-English" you mean `,` (comma) instead of `.` (period) for the decimal point, we need to discuss "Locale".

Comment: No, by non-English numeral I mean non-Arabic numerals - like in Hindi '1' is written as '१', '2' is written as '२', '3' as written as '३'. १ + २ = ३ is the calculation desired by me which in MySQL translates to `SELECT(१ + २);` which should give me the output `३`. Is this possible in any way by way of any special column declaration? Thank you.

Comment: @PayelSenapati - I cannot think of a way other than a tedious 10 `REPLACEs` to change them into arithmetic-friendly characters.  (I see that there are dozens of ways to write the digits.)